# Diplay 3 values of radio button or checkbox within textbox and copy the new text values to clipboard

Tags: html

I am currently trying to build a small html page in where users will be ask to pick at least 2-3 selections using radio button or check box perhaps say.

1st button = "How are"

2nd button = "you"

3rd button = "they"

and the at the bottom of this selections..there will be a texbox..if the user tick 1st,2nd and 3rd radio button/check box,it will populate the text box like this[screenshot][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wf7.png and they are separated by an indention per line..Once the user is done picking the value, he/she will then need to click the button "copy to clipboard" to copy the data from the textbox base on his/her selection..I really need a help on achieving this..I am trying to use html at the moment..as this is the only somehow I am familiar with, lvl 1 of knowledge or just the basic..im sorry im also new here in stackoverflow.my previous question was placed on hold because of my stupidity.my bad.

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function testResults (form) {
      var TestVar1 = form.input[0].checked;
      var TestVar2 = form.input[1].checked;
      var TestVar3 = form.input[3].checked;
        if (TestVar1 == true) {
          form.textbox.value = "How are";
        } else if (TestVar2 == true){
          form.textbox.value = "you";
        } else if (TestVar3 == true){
          form.textbox.value = "they";
        } else if (TestVar1 == false && TestVar2 == false && TestVar3 == false) {
          form.textbox.value = "";
        }
      }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">Choose you answer: <BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="input" VALUE="How are"  onchange="testResults(this.form)">
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="input" VALUE="you" onchange="testResults(this.form)">
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="input" VALUE="they" onchange="testResults(this.form)">
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Copy to clipboard" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
  <P>Your selections are:</P> <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="textbox" NAME="selected" VALUE=""></div><p>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```